# How many distinct values can be stored in floating-point formats?

Tags: numbers, ieee-754

My assumptions for IEEE 754-2008:

binary16 - 2^16 distinct values,
binary32 - 2^32 distinct values,
...
binary128 - 2^128 distinct values.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a trick question.

The floating-point formats define some special values. Whether you count these as distinct depends on your point of view. The following is for double-precision (binary64):

1. There are two representations of 0: with the sign bit 0 or 1 and both the exponent and mantissa all zero. The values are distinguishable by the fact that 1/+0 = infinity and 1/-0 = -infinity. But they compare equal.
2. There are 2 infinities, where the first 12 bits are 0x7ff or 0xfff and the mantissa is all zero. These are not finite real numbers, but they are values.
3. There is a whole range of Not-A-Number (NaN) values, having sign+exponent bits 0x7ff (signaling NaN) or 0xfff ("quiet" NaN) and a nonzero mantissa. Again, these are not real numbers but they are distinguishable values.

So, to summarize:

1. The total number of distinguishable values (real numbers or otherwise) is 2^64.
2. The number of distinct real numbers, excluding infinities and counting zero only once, is `2*(2^11-1)*2^52-1 = 18,437,736,874,454,810,623`.

For binary16, the number of distinct real numbers is `2*(2^5-1)*2^10-1 = 63,487`. For binary32, it's `2*(2^8-1)*2^23-1=4,278,190,079`. For binary128, it's `2*(2^15-1)*2^112-1` or about `3.4*10^38`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about NaN range. So there is 2*(2^8-1)*2^23-1 = 4278190079 for binary32, right?

Comment: Using binary16 for clarity: is it `2*(2^5-1)*(2^10-1)` or `(2*(2^5-1)*2^10)-1`? The latter makes more sense to me, but if it's the former, can you please clarify?